# How to store variable in loss function into instance variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, keras

I am using Keras with Tensorflow.
Since I want to create [LSTM-CRF model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01360), I defined my own loss function using [tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/crf/crf_log_likelihood):

```
def loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
    sequence_lengths = ... # calc from y_true
    log_likelihood, transition_params = tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood(y_pred, y_true, sequence_lengths)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(-log_likelihood)
    self.transition_params = transition_params

    return loss
```

As you know, CRF needs transition params on prediction phase. So I stored **transition_params** into instance variables, **self.transition_params**.

The problem is that self.transition_params has never been updated during minibatch. According to my observation, it seems to be stored only once when compiling the model.

Is there any way to store variable in loss function into instance variable in Keras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the wrong function signature [`tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/crf/crf_log_likelihood), you need to pass the `transition_params` with your current transition params. Following changes will solve the same.

```
log_likelihood, transition_params = 
    tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood(y_pred, y_true, sequence_lengths,  
    transition_params=self.transition_params)
```